# Multiple donut chart not showing percentage

Tags: javascript, d3.js, donut-chart

I try to show multiple donut charts on the same page. But it's not showing. I am using a loop for creating this chart and added multiple html id to show this.

```
var details = [{category: "Doctor", number: 25}, {category: "Shopping", number: 20}, { category: "Restaurants", number: 10}, {    category: "FastFood", number: 5}, { category: "Internet", number: 8},{ category: "Other", number: 32}];
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
    chartScript(details, '#custom-chart-' + i);
function chartScript(details, cls) {
    var width = 300,
        height = 500;
    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeDark2);
    var svg = d3.select(cls).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    details.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b['number'] - a['number'];
    });

    var data = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {
        return d.number;
    })(details);

    var segments = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(80)
        .outerRadius(150)
        .padAngle(.05)
        .padRadius(30);
    var sections = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,250)").selectAll("path").data(data);
    sections.enter().append("path").attr("d", segments).attr("fill", function (d) {
        return colors(d.data.number);
    });
    var content = d3.select("g").selectAll("text").data(data);
    content.enter().append("text").classed("inside", true).each(function (d) {
        var center = segments.centroid(d);
        d3.select(this).attr("x", center[0]).attr("y", center[1]).text(d.data.number + '%')
    })
}
```

I got output like this(1st one is showing % but others are not):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using d3 like this

```
   var sections = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,250)")
```

and in this line

```
var content = d3.select("g").selectAll("text").data(data);
```

instead of d3 You should use

```
var content = sections.select("g").selectAll("text").data(data);
```

That way it will select all the `<g>` tags in the sections

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb: in a D3 code, never use a loop (`for`, `while`, `forEach` etc...) for appending elements.

So, just change that awkward loop for a proper D3 selection...

```
var cls = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(4))
  .enter()
  .append("div");
```

... and not only you will fix the issue you mentioned but also avoid future problems.

Here is a demo using (most of) your code:

```js
var details = [{
  category: "Doctor",
  number: 25
}, {
  category: "Shopping",
  number: 20
}, {
  category: "Restaurants",
  number: 10
}, {
  category: "FastFood",
  number: 5
}, {
  category: "Internet",
  number: 8
}, {
  category: "Other",
  number: 32
}];
var cls = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(4))
  .enter()
  .append("div");
var width = 180,
  height = 180;
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeDark2);
var svg = cls.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
details.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b['number'] - a['number'];
});

var data = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
  return d.number;
})(details);

var segments = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(45)
  .outerRadius(85)
  .padAngle(.05)
  .padRadius(30);
var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(90,90)");

var sections = g.selectAll("path").data(data);
sections.enter().append("path").attr("d", segments).attr("fill", function(d) {
  return colors(d.data.number);
});
var content = g.selectAll("text").data(data);
content.enter().append("text").classed("inside", true).each(function(d) {
  var center = segments.centroid(d);
  d3.select(this).attr("x", center[0]).attr("y", center[1]).text(d.data.number + '%')
})
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```